# How do Pillager Patrols Spawn?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I find raids really fun, and I want to be able to start one. I think that the easiest way to do it is by finding a pillager patrol. How exactly can they spawn? I have only found them twice and only when I have been playing in single player. (My friend sometimes plays on the world with me). I am on a decent-sized island, next to a mushroom biome. What are the spawn conditions of a pillager patrol?

Comment: "I think that the easiest way to do it is by finding a pillager patrol." No, the easiest way is to find a Pillager outpost, and hunting down a patrol captain in a patrol around it. They spawn around these abundantly. Random spawns elsewhere are *rare*.

Comment: I mean the easiest way to start a raid without having to explore too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find all the conditions in the official [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Patrol). For Bedrock edition:

> Patrols spawn naturally after the world age reaches 100 minutes (5 in-game days), then after a delay between 10–11 minutes an attempt is made to spawn a patrol with 20% chance of success. After an attempt is made, the delay is reset.
>
> Patrols spawn around 24-48 blocks away from the player (or more than 48 blocks away if the player is in a village) in any biomes except mushroom fields, mushroom field shore, nether and end.
>
> Additionally, patrols can spawn in biomes where common monsters cannot spawn such as in: river, frozen river, snowy tundra, snowy mountains, legacy frozen ocean.
>
> Patrols spawn on solid blocks at light level 0–7 at the surface, like monsters.

If you never see any, maybe it's the mushroom biome, or your area is too well lit even during the night. Or, if you play with *a lot* of other people, they may be choosing to spawn near them instead.

I play in a single player world, and I see those guys *all the time*. I live near a dark forest, so they always spawn under the trees. Dangerous place to wander off!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for my solution, it really depends if you have cheats on or not. For me, if I wanted to find something that I wouldn't normally be able to find, I would go into the chat box and type in /locate and you just type in want you want to find. For your case, you would type in /locate pillageoutpost it would say like "The nearest Pillager Outpost is at x?, y?, z?. The you just follow the coordinates and voila, you found yourself a Pillager Outpost.

Comment: This would be a good solution if you are okay with using cheats, although this will take away the exploring part of Minecraft that some people enjoy.

Comment: Yeah, I understand your point. When I play Minecraft, I usually build my house in creative, then turn of cheats, but I get everything else in survival.